# Explain PHP Interface for multiple carrier support

Tags: php, class, interface

I am trying to setup a payment gateway controller and using an example from [this url](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-accept-payments-with-stripe--pre-80957).

More specifically here is their code example:

```
// Define the interface
interface BillingProvider {
    public function charge($creditInfo);
}

// Create a Stripe implementation
class StripeBilling {
    public function charge($creditInfo)
    {
        // Stripe_Charge::charge(...);
    }
}

// Create a ServiceX implementation
class ServiceXBilling {
    public function charge($creditInfo)
    {
        // charge user with ServiceX
    }
}
```

And then this:

```
class PaymentController {
    protected $billing;

    public function __construct(BillingProvider $billing)
    {
        $this->billing = $billing;
    }
}
```

How would one implement this properly in a project?

I am trying something like:

```
$paymentController = new PaymentController(new StripeBilling);
```

But then receive an error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to PaymentController::__construct() must implement interface BillingProvider, instance of StripeBilling given
```

Doing some research it appears that both StripeBilling and ServiceXBilling should implement BillingProvider, is this correct?

Comment: `class StripeBilling extends BillingProvider`

Comment: Yes you are correct. `class StripeBilling implements BillingProvider` and `class ServiceXBilling implements BillingProvider`

Comment: Okay thanks. See further comments below in John's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You concrete classes need to [implement the interface](http://php.net/interface).

```
class StripeBilling implements BillingProvider
```

Comment: Okay, thats what I thought. So now is this code correct?

Comment: `$paymentController = new PaymentController(new StripeBilling);`

Comment: How do I call the charge method? If I do:

`$paymentController->charge()`

I get:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method PaymentController::charge()`

Comment: Okay, so I made a public function within the paymentController called charge and have it calling `$this->billing->charge($creditInfo);`, things appear to work as expected. Is this correct? If so, what really is the point of the controller? Why wouldn't I just use my instance of `StripeBilling` instead?